# Disable CheckBox Dynamically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a collection of checkboxes within a form. I am looping through the collection to check and/or disable the checkboxes. The checking works fine; however, I am having an issue with checking if the checkbox is disabled or not. It always return false even when the checkbox is enabled. I looked at the code over and over, and I could not see a anything that could cause this to happen.

> Partial HTML File

```
 <label class="col-lg-3"><div style="padding-left:5px;">View Department</div></label>
 <div class="col-lg-1"><input id="Accounting" name="Accounting" type="checkbox" /> </div>
 <label class="col-lg-3"> Finance</label>
 <div class="col-lg-1"><input id="Finance" name="Finance" type="checkbox" /></div>
 <label class="col-lg-3"> Marketing</label>
 <div class="col-lg-1"><input id="Marketing" name="Marketing" type="checkbox" /></div>
 <div class="col-lg-12">
 <hr style="width:100%;" />
 </div>
```

**//This is how I disable the checkbox**

```
 var collection = document.getElementById('DepartmentClassModal').getElementsByTagName('input');
     if (typeof (e) !== 'undefined') {
         if (e) {
             switch (e) {
                 case 'Education':
                     for (var i = 0; i < collection.length ; i++) {
                         if ((collection[i].id == 'Accounting') || (collection[i].id == 'Finance')) {
                             collection[i].disabled = true
                         } else {
                             collection[i].disabled = false
                         }
                     }
                     break;
             }
         }
     }
```

**//The rendering HTML**

```
<input checked="checked" id="Accounting" name="Accounting" type="checkbox" disabled>
```

**//checking if the field is disabled or not**

```
var isAccountingDisabled = $('#Accounting').is(':disabled');
```

**//The above code always return false.** Why is that?

I added a screen shot of the checkbox property showing that the checkbox is automatically checked and disabled. Even though the checkbox is rendering as disabled, the property does not show it as being disabled.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it returns false ? For me, it gets me "true". http://jsfiddle.net/j9ruj62q/

Comment: I kept paying around with it, and the value was always false. I cleared my cache and tried different browser with the same result.

Comment: @JeanB did you see my answer? Did it work?

Comment: I saw your answer and made the changes, it did not work. The html is rendering correctly on the modal popup; I can see that the correct options are disabled and checked.  The main problem is checking to see if the checkbox is disabled when the user click on update. Using the var isAccountingDisabled = $('#Accounting').is(':disabled'); should have worked given the id #Accounting is unique and disable. I also tried the javascript way var test = document.getElementById('Accounting').disabled;. This too return false always.

Comment: I grabbed the rendering html file and tried it there, and it works fine and give me the expected result.
http://jsfiddle.net/eanamztz/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to read the property using $('#Accounting').is(':checked'); however, I was able to read them using the syntax below.

```
   var collection = document.getElementById('DepartmentClassModal').getElementsByTagName('input');
        $.each(collection, function (index, item) {
            ListDepartments[item.name + "Disabled"] = item.disabled;
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`. In your looping structure you can add the index of the loop also to the id, so that it will be unique. (`Accounting1, Accounting2...`)

Change your code to something like this

```
var checkBoxesCollection = $("#yourparentelement").find("input:checkbox[name='Accounting']");

$.each(checkBoxesCollection, function(){
    if (this.disabled) {
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eanamztz/

Comment: ah nice catch. Didn't notice that in the question.

Comment: Each check box has a unique id, and they are already in the collection. I used a for loop to check and uncheck items in the collection. In addition, I use the same collection to disable and enable the appropriate field. That part work fine. The issue is when I am trying to see if the field is disabled or not. It is always returning false even thought I can see the item is enable. I checked the collection, and it has the correct id and name for each item within the collection. I updated the code to include the collection.

Comment: I noticed that If I changed var isAccountingDisabled = $('#Accounting').is(':enabled');, the result is always true.

Comment: If your generated ids are unique, then you can't use '$("#Accounting")', use the appropriate selector for that element and try checking the disabled attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use `===` instead of `==`

```
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length ; i++) {
                         if ((collection[i].id === 'Accounting') || (collection[i].id === 'Finance')) {
                             collection[i].disabled = true
                         } else {
                             collection[i].disabled = false
                                                 }
     }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators